# Как двигать текст, кнопки и тд. в tkinter

Tags: python

Как можно двигать текст в tkinter? Текст прилегает к верху окна, я хочу чтобы он был чуть-чуть ниже. Как это можно реализовать?
Пример кода:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
root.title('Window')
root['bg'] = '#141717'

text = Label(root, text="Example Text", font='15', bg="#141717", fg='white')
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: вам надо двигать текст постоянно, на протяжении работы приложения? или просто изменить начальное положение?

Comment: метод pack заменить на place https://python-scripts.com/tkinter-layout-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую вам заменить метод pack, на метод place:

```
text.place(rely=0.1, relx = 0.5, anchor='center')
```

Где rely и relx - относительные координаты объекта на экране (относительно левого верхнего угла). А anchor указывает что считать координатами объекта (в примере выше позиционирование элемента будет относительно его центра).